# Web3j : SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: android, geth, web3-java

Im trying to connect to my local Geth client using Web3j Android but getting SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

started Geth node using
`geth --rpc --rpcaddr <my_ip> --rpcport <port>`

Trying to connect via
`Web3j web3 = Web3jFactory.build(new ttpService("http://my_ip:port"));`

Geth node and my android device are on same lan and sharing same internet.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 0.0.0.0

```
--rpcport "YourPort" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```